# Dart List all sealed subtypes

Tags: dart

I'm looking for a way to list all `sealed` subtypes in Dart, like the equivalent of `Enum.values` but for `sealed` subtypes.

For example, an `enum` behaves this way:

```dart
enum Foo { bar, baz }

main() {
  for (final value in Foo.values) {
    switch (value) {
      case Foo.bar:
        print('bar');
      case Foo.baz:
        print('baz');
    }
  }
}

// Prints:
// bar
// baz
```

But if I have a `sealed` class with multiple subtypes:

```dart
sealed class Foo {}
class Bar extends Foo {}
class Baz extends Foo {}
```

In the above case, I don't see a way to iterate over `Bar` and `Baz`. I suppose I would be looking for something like:

```dart
main() {
  switch (Foo.subtypes) {
    case Bar():
      print('bar');
    case Baz():
      print('baz');
  }
}
```

`Foo.subtypes` is not valid, but I was hoping there was a way (other than using mirrors or giving each subtype an `enum`).

Comment: You'll have to use a build stage for this, at least until we get metaprogramming.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature, it really is reflection and should only be done through `dart:mirrors`.

One of the reasons is that there is no single *type* which represents every instantiation of a generic subtype of a sealed class. And there is no easy way to iterate over types to begin with (`Type` objects are not types).